# How do I handle aiohttp exceptions that occur when handling other exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I have a python server setup with aiohttp that is accepting files POST'd to a specific endpoint. I only want to accept a json body, or gzip'd json files. My code is as follows:

```
class Uploader(View):
    async def post(self):
        if not self.request.can_read_body:
            return json_response({'message': 'Cannot read body'}, status=400)
        elif self.request.content_type != 'application/json' and self.request.content_type != 'multipart/form-data':
            return json_response({'message': 'Incorrect data type sent to the server'}, status=400)

        try:
            json_body = await self.request.json()
            # Other bits of code using the json body
        except RequestPayloadError as e:
            # Internal logging here
            return json_response({'message': 'Unable to read payload'}, status=400)
        # Other code for handling ValidationError, JSONDecodeError, Exception
        return json_response({'message': 'File successfully uploaded'}, status=201)
```

When I test this by uploading something that isn't json or gzip'd json, the RequestPayloadError exception is correctly being hit, the internal logging is being done as expected, and the client is being returned the expected response. However, I'm also seeing the following unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_protocol.py", line 428, in start
     await payload.readany()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 325, in readany
     raise self._exception
   File "/web_api/app/views/resources/Uploader.py", line 49, in post
     json_body = await self.request.json()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 512, in json
     body = await self.text()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 506, in text
     bytes_body = await self.read()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/web_request.py", line 494, in read
     chunk = await self._payload.readany()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 325, in readany
     raise self._exception
 aiohttp.web_protocol.RequestPayloadError: 400, message='Can not decode content-encoding: gzip'
```

How am I supposed to handle this currently unhandled exception given that it doesn't seem to be originating in my code, and I'm already handling the one that I'm expecting? Can I suppress aiohttp exceptions somehow?

EDIT: I'm using version 3.1.1 of aiohttp

Answer (score 0):

`Can not decode content-encoding: gzip` points on the problem source.

Your peer sends data with `Content-Encoding: gzip` HTTP header but actually the data is not gzip compressed (other compressor is used or no compressor at all).

As result *aiohttp* fails on decompressing such data with `RequestPayloadError` exception.

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that I'm handling the `RequestPayloadError` already (as I expected this problem to come up), yet I'm still seeing unhandled exceptions stemming from a `RequestPayloadError`

Comment: aiohttp has no magic with exception handling, please double check your code.